# RobolectricTestRunner cannot find manifest file in multi-module maven project

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, robolectric

Let's start with my setup.
I have a multi-module maven project:

```
ProjectRoot
 \moduleA
 \moduleB
```

(relevant) content of moduleA:

```
- AndroidManifest.xml
- src\main\java\HelloWorldActivity
- src\test\java\HelloWorldActivityTest
```

HelloWorldActivityTest is annotated with: @RunWith(RoboelectricTestRunner.class)

My problem is that if I specify the manifest location it will either not work in IntelliJ IDEA or Maven (from command prompt).

If I specify the location to be: "/moduleA/AndroidManifest.xml" it works in IntelliJ
If I specify the location to be "/AndroidManifest.xml" it works in Maven

So the specified path will be interpreted as relative to the project root (in the case of Maven) or the project module (in the case of IntelliJ)

To make it work in both cases I use an ugly workaround right now by setting a property when the project is built with maven and if the property is not set I do:

```
System.setProperty("android.manifest", "moduleA/AndroidManifest.xml");
System.setProperty("android.resources", "moduleA/res");
System.setProperty("android.assets", "moduleA/assets");
```

Please tell me there is a better way.
And no, I will not change the project structure to have a separate test module (unless you give me a very good reason)!

Answer (score 0):

Set up your tests to work with Maven. Then in Intellij go to Edit Configurations-->Defaults-->Junit and change your "Working Directory" to **$MODULE_DIR$**. You'll probably have to delete your previous test run configurations for this to take effect.

[image]